# How can I access postgreSQL database from a mobile phone?

Tags: postgresql, remote-access

I am designing a database in pgAdmin4 and postgreSQL. I am new in it, and I would like to know if there is a way to access and modify this same database from my mobile phone. I am trying with RemoDb APP but cannot manage to properly connect... any advice? Thank you!

Comment: Where are you hosting the database?

Comment: Why you are not connection through ```API```?

Comment: Probably the most versatile way is to use SSH to connect to remote host and then using its local facilities (including `psql`).

Comment: Can you please explain this procedures more precisely? I am using windows, I am bit lost! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `PgAdmin4` in the mobile browser.

[image: Ipad Mozila]